# jquery addClass has no effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="cell1" class="cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div id="cell2" class="cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
    <div id="cell3" class="cell"><div class="content"></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}

.cell {
    background-color: red;
}

#cell1 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

#cell2 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

#cell3 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

.white {
    background-color: white;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cell', function(e) {

    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('white');
    $(this).parent().children().children().removeClass('yellow');

    $(this).addClass('white');
    $(this).find('.content').addClass('yellow');
});
```

The problem I am having now is addClass('yellow') has no effect. However, if I delete the background-color in content class, it works. Any thoughts why?

jsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/rexwang/FWh6E/

Thanks for the answers, it works! But I really don't like using addClass and removeClass, is  it posible to use e.currentTarget.id to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, even though it works, I still don't like this way. Is that possible to use e.currentTarget.id to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate the things. Everything that is possible to achieve with CSS, should be achieved with CSS.

Answer (score 4):

It works but the `.yellow` background style is overriden by the `.content` background style, since in the stylesheet `.content` class goes after `.yellow`.

One way is to swap these classes in the CSS.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/FWh6E/2/

Answer (score 4):

The `.addClass()` **is** working but because of the way CSS rules are applied, the `.content` selector has more *weight* than the `.yellow` single class selector - see [CSS specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) for a Star Wars themed explanation of specificity.

In the [CSS documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order) the final clause is being used to determine which rule is applied.

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

So you could either swap the order of the rules in the CSS file, moving `.yellow` after `.content`, or give the `.yellow` selector more *weight* by adding another selector to the chain, for example:

```
.content.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put !important for this

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Try this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWh6E/4/)

Comment: `!important` is far not the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

JSFIddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj4PT/

Your code

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Change to

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow!important;
}
```

`.content` background style was overriding  `.yellow` style

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Change CSS `yellow` as below:

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow!important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWh6E/3/)